# Reassign `this` in Java class

Tags: java, reference, this, abstract-data-type

I'm just fooling around in Java right now, trying to implement something similar to a stack using linked lists.

```
class ListStack {

    int value;
    int size;
    ListStack next;

    public ListStack (int add) {
        this.size = 1;
        this.value = add;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public void push (int add) {
        this.next = this;
        this.value = add;
        this.size++;
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (this.size == 0) { throw new EmptyListStackException(); }
        int i = this.value;
        this = this.next;
        this.size--;
        return i;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public int peek() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Basically it's an insertion-in-front linked list which also removes from front. NetBeans pops an error when I try to do `this = this.next`; it says I cannot reassign final value `this`.

I'd like my final implementation to do something like the below:

```
ListStack var = new ListStack(5); //var is now 5 -> null
var.push(3); //var is now 3 -> 5 -> null
int val = varr.pop(); //var is now 5 -> null, val == 3
```

Commenting put that `this = this.next` code, the rest seems to work.

```
ListStack a = new ListStack(5);
System.out.println(a.size()); //prints 1
System.out.println(a.peek()); //prints 5
a.push(4);
System.out.println(a.size()); //prints 2
System.out.println(a.peek()); //prints 4
a.push(6);
System.out.println(a.size()); //prints 3
System.out.println(a.peek()); //prints 6
a.push(1);
System.out.println(a.size()); //prints 4
System.out.println(a.peek()); //prints 1
//a is 1 -> 6 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
```

Comment: `this` refers to the current object. It's like saying: 
"I am" or "my name is". You can't change who you are.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis life lessons along with java lessons

Comment: That's because you cannot reassign `this`.  What you need to do is have an anchor object for your list.  Otherwise you have no way to add to/delete from the head of the list.

Comment: (And, just out of curiosity, what do you think `push` is going to do?)

Comment: `this.next = this;` is not a good idea either. Have you considered backing your Stack with an ArrayList?

Comment: @HotLicks, `.push()` would effectively "shift it right" if that makes sense. `this.next` would become `this`.

Comment: No, push will assign `next` to point at the object containing `next`.  (Think about it -- there's no other object around, since you didn't create one.)

Comment: (You have a fairly serious misunderstanding of what an object is, vs a reference (pointer) to an object.)

Comment: I've edited the question to show some other code. `.push()` works as intended.

Comment: Basically, you've written a class that says it's supposed to be a "stack", which is a collection of elements, but your implementation looks like an implementation of _one element_ of a stack.  (Individual elements would have a `next`, but an entire stack would not.)  Consider breaking this into two classes.

Comment: If all `push` is supposed to store one number and increment another then, yes, it works "as intended".  By that measure `pop` is working "as intended" when it won't even compile.

Comment: See also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-reference-to-this-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a conceptual error in your code: basically you are not creating any new stack element with your push method.

But the problem is that calling the class listStack becomes misleading, because actually what you want to create are new elements of the stack, so you should create a class node maybe.
Moreover you can't ovveride "this" because it is a java keyword and it always refers to the current object.

To give you a hint of what to do to implement a stack as a linked list you should create `class Node` with a value field `value` and a reference to the previous `Node` (the first node will just have a null pointer) .

In the class `ListStack`you should have a reference to the last node and its `push()` method should create a new Node and set this one as the new last node.

Comment: Cheers, although I was able to implement it without a separate node class. http://pastebin.com/ySRp0nZA

Comment: @riista - I have seen stack schemes where an "entry" was used as the "head", instead of having a separate class for the "head", but that required that the special "entry" not be used to contain stack data.

Comment: ... and there would be other issues due to porosity of the abstraction boundaries; e.g. the API would most likely break if operations were called on a node that isn't currently the top of the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Let me point you in right direction. As others have commented, this stack does not work properly Consider doing something like this:

```
public class ListStack {
    
    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

                //inner class which holds your each element and reference to next
                //fill all details required     
    }
    
    private Node head;
    private int size;
    
    public ListStack() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    
    public void push(int value) {
        Node temp = new Node(value);
        if(head == null)
            head = temp;
        else {
            temp.setNext(head); // provide link to already existing stack
            head = temp;       // bring new element on top
        }
    }
    
    public int pop() {
        if(head==null);
            //throw exception
        int temp = head.getValue();
        head = head.getNext(); //remove element and bring down the stack
        return temp;
    }
}
```